# footer using nested divs

Tags: css, html

i am trying to add a footer to my website but the text keeps moving around.

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footerchild">
    <a href=".html">1</a>
  </div>
  <div id="footerchildone">
    <a href=".html">2</a>
  </div>
  <div id="footerchildtwo">
    <a href=".html">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="footerchildthree">
    <a href=".html">4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#footer {
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: #812;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 40px 1px #444;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1040px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}

#footerchildone {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 500px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

#footerchildtwo {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 350px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

#footerchildthree {
  float:right;
  margin-top: -22px;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
```

I want each column to be centrated with a specific distance, but when i move for instance childthree, the second child follows with it. It shouldnt be like that because i have given each of them a separate div. What is the problem?

Comment: they're relatively positioned towards each other, there is no css attributes there to instruct them to behave separately, you should use position: absolute if you want them to disregard each other

Comment: i tried position: absolute, but it did not work. did you mean for each child?

Comment: yes johnny, they all should be absolutely positioned, think of it as lego parts, that is if u really want them fixed in place, but let me tell u it is highly unusual in web to fix parts in place, they should flow, just in case u change content in the future, they should adapt without much trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are trying to accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/65GaS/5/

It's that simple or I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vvjAJ/

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footerchild"><a href=".html">1</a></div>
<div id="footerchildone"><a href=".html">2</a></div>
<div id="footerchildtwo"><a href=".html">3</a></div>
<div id="footerchildthree"><a href=".html">4</a></div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
#footer
{margin-left: 100px;background: #812;box-shadow: 1px 2px 40px 1px #444;border: 1px solid black;width: 1040px;height: 300px;position: absolute;}
#footerchild{float:left;width:260px;margin-top: 50px;text-align:center;}
#footerchildone{float: left;width:260px;text-align:center;margin-top: 50px}
#footerchildtwo{float: left;width:260px;text-align:center;margin-top: 50px}
#footerchildthree{float:left; margin-top: 50px;text-align:center;width:260px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add text-align:center to center the text for parent div and make every child div as position:relative; display:inline-block; automatically it will align center for parent div and make sure to remove float:right for child divs. hope this will work for you.